# Python: ctypes CDLL('library.so') Specified Modul not found

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, shared-libraries, ctypes

I am trying to use a simple C++ function within python3.
Following a tutorial I built a shared libray (".so") and tried to call the funktion within python with the ctypes.CDLL() function.

Compiling the .cpp and executing the .py went well on the command line, but when I copied all files into an IDE (PyCharm in my case) and run the code from there I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../test/wrapper.py", line 26, in <module>
    test = ctypes.CDLL('library.so').foo_bar_function(a, b)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module was not found
```

I already tried specifying the full path to the library.so, without luck.

I'm aware that there are toolsets as the Boost.Python Library which can help extending python with c/c++ functions. But as the functions do not require anything special, are only "static" methods and are quite simple, I thought I would not have to go through that hassle. All my function should do is getting some arrays from python, manipulating the array with simple  operations and returning an int.

What I did:

- Created two files:

  .../test/function.cpp
  .../test/wrapper.py

function.cpp:

```
#include <valarray>

bool foo_function(const std::valarray<float> &a, const int b) {
    float f = 0.0;
    std::valarray<float> above = a[a < f];
    return above.size() >= b;
}

int bar_function(const std::valarray<float> &a, const int b) {
    bool b = foo_function(a,b[0]);
    ... SOME OTHER CODE ...
    return 0;
}

extern "C" int foo_bar_function(float *a, int *b, int c) {
    std::valarray<float> v (a, c);
    ... SOME OTHER CODE ...
    int i = bar_function(v, b);
    return i;
}
```

and wrapper.py

```
import ctypes

py_a = [10,5,6,2,1,1,1,6,3,1]
c_a = (ctypes.c_float * len(py_a))(*py_a)

py_b = [1,1,2]
c_b = (ctypes.c_int * len(py_b))(*py_b)

test = ctypes.CDLL('library.so').foo_bar_function(c_a, c_b)

print(test)
```

then I ran:

```
...\test> g++ -shared -c -fPIC function.cpp -o function.o
...\test> g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,library.so -o library.so function.o
...\test> python wrapper.py
0 (expected output from c++ function)
```

So within the cmd all went as expected.

What else could I try?

Comment: In PyCharm, what is the result of `os.getcwd()`?  Is your .so in that path?  When specifying the full path, did you use a a raw string `r'c:\path'` or forward slashes `c:/path` where a backslash can't be misinterpreted as an escape?  As an aside, in your `foo_bar_function`, `sizeof(a)` is the size of `float*`, not the size of the `py_a` array passed in.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, the .py and the .so reside in the same folder and printing the os.getcwd() points to that. I tried forward slashes and double backward. By now I'm sure its the about including valarray.. When I'm not #including anything it works like a (py)charm.. 
Ah thanks for pointing that out, that came from quickly reducing the sample, in the code I pass another int with the array size.

Comment: A tool like SysInternals procmon.exe can help track down where PyCharm is looking for your library and any dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look! Any way I could directly bundle valarray into the .so or compile a seperate shared library out of it and include that one in my code?

Comment: FWIW I used MSVC++ here at home and compiling your extern "C" function  with a valarray "just worked" linking to the shared C++ runtime and using ctypes.

Comment: sorry im farily new to c++ and compiling such, what exactly do you mean by "linking to the shared c++ runtime"? can you share the commands you used to compile and create the shared library with msvc++?

Comment: `cl /EHsc /W4 /MD /LD test.cpp`.  The flags enable C++ exception handling, maximize warnings, dynamic link to the runtime, and create a DLL.  Note the output is `test.dll` not `test.so`.  Maybe that works with `g++` on Windows, but to me .so is a Linux library.

Comment: I did a quick check and renaming `test.dll` to `test.so` and using `ctypes.CDLL('test.so')` did still load for me.

Comment: thank you, that helped a lot! though I have to admit using a shared library did not gave me the speed up I expected (at least mutlicore), thus I used jit's no python.